# How to refresh Bing Maps AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, bing-maps

I create Bing Maps AJAX control and initialize it with always the same values: lat, lng and zoom level. This is a default aerial map type and a maximum zoom level. And every time I get the following image:

http://i50.tinypic.com/acturr.jpg

There is no documented method (or not) to refresh the current area so I should to do zoom out and zoom in using mouse every time, it's annoying. For Google Maps I found a useful trick:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, 'resize');
```

Does Bing Maps AJAX API have something similar?

Comment: Then why not just switch to Google Maps API? (from my experience, their documentation and overall API structure is far better than Bing's)

Comment: Can you maybe post some code of what you do, and a live demo ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) would be very handy as well to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but in this case it is useless. http://jsfiddle.net/Jd7pN/ there is a simple example but sometime I see a picture above instead of proper trees and road. It occurs in IE 8,9 or inside its WebMap COM control. Probably it is because of bad connections, I often see not properly loaded tiles, anyway it does not matter. Google has a way to just refresh control. I would like to have such stuff for Bing.

Comment: did you get any solution for bing map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently encountered a similar issue on Bing maps AJAX V7:

On some browsers (Mostly on Chrome), if the map is not present on the viewport (you have to scroll to reach it), then it initializes improperly.
I have reported the issue to MSDN but didn't get any useful answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/439c33bc-a1ed-4e74-a019-f7fecb809030/scroll-issue-on-chrome-with-ajax-v7-control

To fix this issue, I have used two things:

- First of all, I had to find a way to force the Bing map to refresh (didn't found any solution on the internet nor object method to do that). After a lot of tests I came out with a solution:

  ```
  map.setMapType(Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.mercator);
  setTimeout(function(){map.setMapType(Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.auto);}, 1)
  ```

  Indeed, changing the viewport to "mercator" then back to another forces the map to refresh (the setTimeout makes the action asynchronous)
- I then have added a lib that triggers an event when an element is entering the viewport in order to trigger the force refresh every time the map enters the viewport